# PowerShell fails to interpret commands such as "which"

Tags: powershell, shell

My windows Powershell gives the expected results when interpreting commands such as "date" and "echo", while problems occur when it interprets such commands as "which" and "tail".
I thought it might be that I haven't add the address of these commands to the target directories, but where can I probably find these commands.

[What happens when I apply "which", with the same thing happening when applying "tail"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAhnu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which` and `tail` are the names of *external programs*, which are unrelated to PowerShell. These programs can only be expected to be present on *Unix-like* platforms, not (natively) on Windows. (However, they would be present in Unix-like *subsystems* on Windows, such as [WSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows%20Subsystem%20for%20Linux).)

By contrast, `date` and `echo` are (potentially) commands that are *built into* PowerShell, irrespective of what platforms it runs on:

- `echo` is an *alias* of PowerShell's [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlet on all platforms.
- `date` - unless an external program by that name is present in a directory listed in `$env:PATH` on a given platform - refers to the *built in* [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) cmdlet.

  - Note: This relies on PowerShell's ill-conceived *default verb* feature, which falls back on prefixing a command name with `Get-` if no command form is found by the given name. This shouldn't be relied upon, both in the interest of conceptual clarity and to avoid unnecessary overhead. Also, this fallback is (unexpectedly) *not* reported by the `Get-Command` discussed below, and also not by [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) - see [GitHub issue #3987](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3987).

Use [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) to determine what command form, if any, a given name refers to (add `-All` to see if potentially *multiple* forms exist, with the *effective* one being listed first).